# Django redirect to form page and submit the form?

Tags: django, django-views

Right now. I have a search function in my page to search for item id. When I click search, I will render the same page with the result items and show item. And in other pages where I also display the item id, I want to add a link to the id to go to the same page where I search for that id.

Example: id: 123, I want the same page when:
1. search '123' in my search page(my search only accept exact match)
2. In other pages, click '123', go to the search page with results

How should I achieve this, I have tried many ways which don't wok.

Comment: you should show some code showing what you have tried and also to give us a better idea of what you want.

Comment: I don't record all the code changes. I will try to explain more clearly

Comment: I got this solved by making the hyperlink using POST method using javascript. It may be not the best solution but do solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the GET method that HTML forms provide. When you perform a search from the first page, you must make sure that you are doing so using the GET method in the form. This will append the form data into the URL.

E.g. If you have a 'name' field in your form which has 'John' inputted. The submission of this form will compose a URL like so:

```
http://someurl.com/?name=John
```

This can then be accessed using the Django request object:

```
name = request.GET['name']
```

You've probably done something similar already for displaying your search results. So, all you need to do is create a link in your second page that redirects to the search page with GET request variables appended.

E.g.

```
<a href="{% url 'search_page' %}?searchterm=232> Item 232 </a>
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the original search using POST method? My idea right now is using different a new url to catch that and redirect to the search page as if the call is made on search page.

Comment: I would highly recommend using the form with GET if the information being handled is not sensitive.

Please refer to this link to view differences in GET and POST:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp